# Bootstrap 4 Tab to Accordion. How to?

Tags: tabs, accordion, bootstrap-4

I googled and found how to make Bootstrap 3 tab to accordion in responsive here [`Bootstrap 3 tab to accordion`](https://codepen.io/dliebswager/pen/JfCLg), but I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I don't know how to convert it to Bootstrap 4 tab to accordion. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: put code - your link is blocked by SO.

Answer (score 38):

> As indicated in the comments, the original answer was written for [Bootsrap 4 Beta 2](https://www.bootstrapdash.com/bootstrap-4-release-date/). The released Bootstrap 4 version requires two changes in the markup/css. Hence the update.

In Bootstrap 4 you can achieve that functionality with the following markup.
(As the built-in snippet viewer mixes up things sometimes when css @media queries involved, I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/YYyjYJ) too.)

Compared to BS 4 Beta 2 there are these two required changes:

- First, the way the tabs are hidden are changed: Earlier `.tab-pane`s *opacity* was managed by the `.fade` class, but in the released verion it is the `.fade:not(.show)` selector, which has higher precedence. So, to override the *opacity* `.tab-pane` needed to be changed to `.tab-content > .tab-pane` in the css.
- Second, the handling of collapsible groups are changed as well. Previously it was the toggle button which required the `data-parent` attribute. However since the release version `data-parent` needs to go onto the collapsible element.

The updated code for **Bootstrap 4.1.3** is like so:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-A" href="#pane-A" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–A–</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-B" href="#pane-B" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–B–</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-C" href="#pane-C" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–C–</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
        <div id="pane-A" class="card tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-A">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <!-- Note: `data-parent` removed from here -->
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-A" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-A">
                        Collapsible Group Item A
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <!-- Note: New place of `data-parent` -->
            <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" data-parent="#content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
                <div class="card-body">
                    [Tab content A]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pane-B" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-B">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-B" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-B">
                        Collapsible Group Item B
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" data-parent="#content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
                <div class="card-body">
                    [Tab content B]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pane-C" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-C">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-C" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-C">
                        Collapsible Group Item C
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#content" aria-labelledby="heading-C">
                <div class="card-body">
                    [Tab content C]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-tabs {
    display:none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .nav-tabs {
        display: flex;
    }

    .card {
        border: none;
    }

    .card .card-header {
        display:none;
    }  

    .card .collapse{
        display:block;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px){
    /* 
     * Changed selector to `.tab-content > .tab-pane` in order to override `.fade:not(.show)`
     * In BS4 Beta `.tab-pane`s were rendered hidden by just `.fade`
     */
    .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**Original answer for Bootstrap 4 Beta 2**:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/GPgOOE)

```css
.nav-tabs {
    display:none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .nav-tabs {
        display: flex;
    }

    .card {
        border: none;
    }

    .card .card-header {
        display:none;
    }  

    .card .collapse{
        display:block;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px){
    .tab-pane {
        display: block !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-A" href="#pane-A" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–A–</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-B" href="#pane-B" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–B–</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-C" href="#pane-C" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–C–</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
        <div id="pane-A" class="card tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-A">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-A" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="collapse-A">
                        Collapsible Group Item A
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
                <div class="card-body">
                    [Tab content A]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pane-B" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-B">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-B" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="collapse-B">
                        Collapsible Group Item B
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
                <div class="card-body">
                    [Tab content B]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pane-C" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-C">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-C" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="collapse-C">
                        Collapsible Group Item C
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-C">
                <div class="card-body">
                    [Tab content C]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `data-parent` should be on the collapse containers now.

Comment: @TimVermaelen what do you mean I can see you are right (i.e. this markup no longer works bootstrap v4.1.3) but I have moved `data-parent` around like a mad man and they still disappear (when in mobile) what am I missing?

Comment: @TimVermaelen EG: shrink this down to mobile to see the bug https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwoKOY#anon-login

Comment: @dferenc https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/YYyjYJ is your original 4.0.0 beta.. (works only in 4.0.0) the version I link here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwoKOY#anon-login is 4.1.3 (and is not working)

Comment: @MrHeelis, please check your bootstrap version first (js & css), as it seems to be still beta 4.0.0.

Comment: for 4.1.3 and above @TimVermaelen 's solution is right

Comment: @TimVermaelen thanks for the note! While the change in `data-parent` is indeed important, it was more the change in the css which rendered the OP out of date in the first place.

Comment: Found the best solution here: https://codepen.io/mikeshema/pen/jxQEKw

Answer (score 3):

Current Bootstrap 4 versions, suggests the `data-parent` should be put on the collapse containers.

*To add accordion-like group management to a collapsible area, add the data attribute data-parent="#selector".*

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-A" href="#pane-A" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–A–</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-B" href="#pane-B" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–B–</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="tab-C" href="#pane-C" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–C–</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
        <div id="pane-A" class="card tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-A">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-A" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-A">Collapsible Group Item A</a></h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#content" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
           <div class="card-body">[Tab content A]</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pane-B" class="card tab-pane fade show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-B">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-B" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-B">Collapsible Group Item B</a></h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#content" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
            <div class="card-body">[Tab content B]</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pane-C" class="card tab-pane fade show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-C">
            <h5 class="mb-0"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-C" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-C">           Collapsible Group Item C</a></h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#content" aria-labelledby="heading-C">
            <div class="card-body">[Tab content C]</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#via-data-attributes

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmbdqa)

Comment: FYI _ Tim, great work but with 2 slight bugs 1)  if you pick tab C ([Tab content C]) or Tab B ([Tab content B]) in large then resize down Accordion Title A (and or Title C) disappears, also when you select a "tab" or "accordion" in either mode, the content selected isn't preserved in the displayed accordion/tab in resized mode

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll compare them with my last integration tomorrow. Should be possible to sort this out with data-attributes only.

Comment: Or today ^^ Issue related to CSS. Please note the changed selector `.tab-content .tab-pane`.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it's not too late to answer for `Bootstrap 5` users

I'm using `Bootstrap 5` and here is my solution without writing extra `JS code`

```
<!-- HTML part -->
<!-- nav/tab links -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item border mx-1 rounded">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#pane-A" id="tab-A" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item border mx-1 rounded">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#pane-B" id="tab-B" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item border mx-1 rounded">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#pane-C" id="tab-C" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab C</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- nav/tab links ends -->

<!-- nav/tab -->
<div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
  <div id="pane-A" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
    <div class="border rounded p-2" role="tab" id="heading-A">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-A" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-A">
          Collapsible Group Item A
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" data-bs-parent="#content" role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="heading-A">
      <div class="card-body">
        [Tab content A]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="pane-B" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
    <div class="border rounded p-2" role="tab" id="heading-B">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-B" aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapse-B">
          Collapsible Group Item B
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#content" role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="heading-B">
      <div class="card-body">
        [Tab content B]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="pane-C" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
    <div class="border rounded p-2" role="tab" id="heading-C">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-C" aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapse-C">
          Collapsible Group Item C
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" data-bs-parent="#content"
      aria-labelledby="heading-C">
      <div class="card-body">
        [Tab content C]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- nav/tab ends -->
```

And here my style file content for this

```
.nav-pills {
    display:none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .nav-pills {
        display: flex;
    }
    .tab-pane .border {
        display:none;
    }  
    .tab-pane .collapse{
        display:block;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px){
    .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

You can change the parameters if you want this to work with tablet view

Answer (score 2):

I made this bootstrap 4 tab to accordion using jquery.... I hope it works :)

```
function tabToAccordion(){
    var navTab = $(".nav-tabs"),
        tabContent = $(".tab-content");
        // hiding the navtabs
    navTab.hide();
    // appending each link to respective tab-pane
        navTab.find("li").each(function(){
            var destination = $($(this).find(".nav-link").attr("href"));
            var anchor = $(this).find(".nav-link");
            // removing unused attributes and adding tabContent-toggler class
            anchor.removeAttr("data-toggle role aria-controls aria-selected").addClass("tabContent-toggler").insertBefore(destination);
        });
    var tabToggler = $('.tabContent-toggler'),
    tabPane = tabContent.find(".tab-pane"),
    // get all classes in tab pane for further usage and replace tab-pane with empty data
    nonActiveTabPane = tabContent.find(".tab-pane:not(.active)").attr("class");
    tabPaneClass = tabPane.attr('class');
    tabPaneClass = tabPaneClass.replace(nonActiveTabPane,"");
    tabToggler.click(function(e){
        // get the destination of clicked element
        var destination = $($(this).attr("href"));
        // if not this element then remove active class
        $(this).parent().find(tabToggler).not($(this)).removeClass("active");
        //if not clicked destination then remove all other class except tab-pane
        $(this).parent().find('.tab-pane').removeClass(tabPaneClass);
        // now toggle active class
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        // also toggle all other class in tab-pane
        destination.toggleClass(tabPaneClass);
        // if this element dont have active class then remove all other class from tab-pane
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
            destination.removeClass(tabPaneClass);
        }
        // first element of nested tab-pane should be active
        if(destination.has(tabToggler)){
            var tabTogglerFirstChild = destination.find(".tabContent-toggler:first-child"),
            tabTogglerFirstDestination = $(tabTogglerFirstChild.attr("href"));
            tabTogglerFirstChild.addClass("active");
            tabTogglerFirstDestination.addClass(tabPaneClass);
        }
        // preventing default behaviour of element
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
// check if device is mobile and if so only run the function
if(/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    tabToAccordion();
}
```